# filedescriptor use to render pdf file from external storage in android

Tags: android, android-external-storage, pdfrenderer

I have downloaded a pdf file in external storage directory and i want to reder it using pdfrender in android.
i have successfully rendered the pdf saved in my asset folder but now i need to render the file that is saved in external directory. here is the code i am using

`String filePath1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Mock-up Presentation.pdf";
//filePath1 is the location for file i want to render
        File file = new File(filePath1);
        mFileDescriptor=getActivity().getAssets().openFd("sample.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();//sample pdf is saved in asset folder in project which i have rendered //already
        // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
        mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open up a `FileInputStream` on the file, then call `getFD()` on the `FileInputStream` to get the `FileDescriptor`.

Comment: i will be needing a ParcelFileDescriptor to Pass it to PdfRenderer().
mFileDescriptor is of Type ParcelFileDescriptor

Comment: Call [`open()` on `ParcelFileDescriptor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#open%28java.io.File,%20int%29), then.

Comment: Doesn't need to use FileInputStream . I used this =>  mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE)); and it worked. thanks anyway :)

Comment: file means the path for file

Answer (score 0):

If you faced this problem in project that is targeting android 9+,
Get Complete Code For Solution.[from Here](https://github.com/zworthkey-pvt-ltd/ZWK-PDF-Renderer)
Then you can follow some Steps:
Step 1: Open an Intent for selecting PDF file.

/*This Code will help to open Intent..*/

```
public final int PDF_REQUEST_CODE =1200;
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent,PDF_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Step 2: now catch result returned by above intent.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) 
{ 
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if(requestCode==PDF_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
 {
  Uri uri=data.getData();
  PdfRendererBasicViewModel pdfRendererBasicViewModel =new 
  ViewModelProvider(this).get(PdfRendererBasicViewModel.class);              
  pdfRendererBasicViewModel.setUri(uri);
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PdfRendererBasicFragment())
                        .commitNow();
 }
}
```

Step 3: Need some Modifications on pdfRendererBasicViewModel class.
First of all need to declare methods that set/get file's Uri in viewmodel.
as we called setUri(). in onActivityResult() method.

After That update replace openPdfRenderer() method with
private static Uri uri; `
private void openPdfRenderer() throws IOException {

```
    if(getUri()!=null){
        
         mFileDescriptor =
                getApplication().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(getUri(), "r");
    }
    if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
        mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
    }
}`
```

now try to run ...

If You want a complete Solution then you can import from github  [here](https://github.com/zworthkey-pvt-ltd/ZWK-PDF-Renderer)